# Custom function, that works with structured references in Excel tables

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, udf

How to write `UDF` in Visual Basic for Applications that can work with structured references like this:

```
=UDF([Colomn1])
```

or this:

```
=UDF(if(len([Colomn1])>1,[Colomn1]))
```

Any ideas?

@Rory, this function work with range, but not work with reference to column. Result values are repeated.

```
Function udff(sRange As Range) As Variant
    Dim valueArr As Variant
    valueArr = sRange.Value
    ReDim resArr(LBound(valueArr, 1) To UBound(valueArr, 1), LBound(valueArr, 2) To UBound(valueArr, 2))
    For i = LBound(valueArr, 1) To UBound(valueArr, 1)
        For j = LBound(valueArr, 2) To UBound(valueArr, 2)
            resArr(i, j) = valueArr(i, j) & "!"
        Next j
    Next i
    udff = resArr
End Function
```

Comment: When you say `len(Column1)` ,What does that mean?rows count or something else.You can define your required functions using `Function`

Comment: A structured reference simply returns a range, so it's the same as any other UDF.

Comment: This should be in the original question using edit. Not in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax appears wrong. **[Colomn1]** should be **[@Colomn1]** (and possibly spelled correctly).

```
Function udf(rng As Range)
    udf = rng * 2
End Function
```

[image: colomn1]

**Do not** confuse the ability to use associative full column references with true worksheet range references (e.g. A1 or A:A) with [ListObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247.aspx) (*aka* structured) table references.

[image: colomn2]

Comment: Synax is not wrong. Built-in functions work with [Colomn1] well. [@Colomn1] is slower then [Colomn1], because in first one Excel loops values, in secont Range passed as a parameter

Comment: See addendum added.